# What could be causing the following error in my ingress-srv.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Building a Microservices app(Node/React) with docker and kubernetes and I keep getting the following error when I run the `skaffold dev` command.

```sh
- stderr: "error: unable to recognize ~/infra/k8s/ingress-srv.yaml\": no matches for kind \"Ingress\" in version \"extensions/v1beta1\"\n"
```

This is my ingress-srv.yaml file:

```js
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-serv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
          - path: "/api/users/?(.*)"
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

And this is my skaffold.yaml file

```js
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts: 
    - image: mutuadocker/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync: 
        manual: 
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` to `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`
so your file would look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-serv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
          - path: "/api/users/?(.*)"
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Refer to [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#ingress-v1-networking-k8s-io).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is partly old but...
Here's my answer.

*Make sure the **pathType** is inside the **paths** array; not outside it and not as a standalone array*

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-serv
  annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/api/users/?(.*)"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```